# Emitir evento para vue-js-modal

Tags: vue.js

tengo un componente desde el cual abro una modal con la libreria vue-js-modal y quiero desde ese componente hijo que he abierto pasarle unos datos al padre a traves de eventos. Alguna idea ?

Este es mi metodo de abrir la modal :

```
openModal(type){
      this.$modal.show(
          Elementos,
          { property:type , update:this.update},
          { styles:"background-color: #D3D3D3 ; border-radius: 67px" ,clickToClose:false,maxHeight:500,height:'auto'},
          {update: this.cerrar}
      )
    }
```

Desde el hijo lanzo este emit

```
  save(){
      this.$emit("update", this.text);
}
```

Pues resulta que asi no lanza el methodo cerrar